# Check whether a decomposition is in 3nf

Tags: database-theory, databases

In a database systems course, we have been presented with the following definition for third normal form (3NF):

> A relation $R$ is in 3NF means:
> a nontrivial dependency $A_1,\dots,A_n\to B_1,\dots B_m$ can hold in $R$ only if
> $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ is a key (either minimal or super) in $R$
> or
> for $1 \leq i \leq m$, each $B_i$ is a part of a minimal key.

Given the relation $R(A,B,C,D)$ with FDs:$A\to C$ and $C,D\to B$, is the following decomposition of $R$ in 3NF?:
$R_1(A,C)$ $R_2(A,B,D)$.

I think it is not in $3NF$:

- In $R_1$, $\{A\}$ is a key and $A\to C$ is a nontrivial dependency. It meets the first condition, so $R_1$ is in $3NF$.
- In $R_2$, $C,D\to B$ is a nontrivial dependency and $\{A\}$ is a key. The first condition is not met because $\{C,D\}$ is not a key and $\{B\}$ is not a part of a key.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency `C, D -> B` does not hold in `R2` since the three attributes are not present in it and that dependency cannot be derived by taking the closure of the union of the the projection of the dependencies over `R1` and `R2`.

So the decomposition is in 3NF (actually it is in BCNF), but the dependency `C, D -> B` is lost. A decomposition that preserves data and dependencies is for instance:

```
R1(A, C)
R2(B, C, D)
R3(A, D)
```